# Java inner for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have to find all possibilities to distribute n things to k containers. The containers all should have a different size so I made k inner for-loops for counting every possibility. Sorry for the bad explanation, but my english is not that good.

Example code that works for 3 Containers:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < container[0]; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < container[1]; j++)
         for (int k = 0; k < container[2]; k++)
             if ((i + j + k) == n)
                 Possibilities++;
```

Now i need to know how to make k for loops so that it works for 2 and for 10.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with:possibilities to distribute n things to k containers.what's n in if(....n).

Comment: Can you give example input and output?

Comment: Does the Order of the containers matter?  i.e. if N=10, and there are 4 containers, is 4, 3, 2, 1 different from 3, 4, 1, 2?  Can any of the containers be empty?

Comment: the containers can be empty, and the orde matters. Possibilities are the possibilities where the sum of all containers is n. for example i want to know how many possibilities there are to devide 10 on 3 containers, the first one with a size of three, second one with a size of four and third one with a size of five.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that `containers` holds the size of each container. Perhaps the simplest solution would be to just set the size of any containers you don't use to zero. Then you can have (say) 10 nested loops but if there are only 2 containers then set all the sizes above 2 to zero.

However nested loops are not really the best way to handle this. This is likely to be a good use for recursion.

```
private int combinationCount(int[] containerSizes, int from, int total) {
    if (total == 0 || from == containerSizes.length - 1)
        return 1;
    int combinations = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= Math.min(total, containerSizes[from]); i++)
        combination += combinationCount(containerSizes, from + 1, total - i);
    return combinations;
}
```

This would be called with `combinationCount(containers, 0, n)`. You could remove the `from` argument altogether by either copying the array in each recursive call or passing a `List` and then a sublist in the recursive calls.

Here is my test code for your information:

```
System.out.println(combinationCount(IntStream.range(10, 30).toArray(), 0, 10));
```

Which returns 20030010

I'll explain how this works:

```
if (total == 0 || from == containerSizes.length - 1)
    return 1;
```

If the total of the remaining containers is zero then there's only 1 combination because all the remaining containers must be empty. Similarly if there's only one container left there's only 1 combination because it must have all the remaining items.

```
int combinations = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= Math.min(total, containerSizes[from]); i++)
    combination += combinationCount(containerSizes, from + 1, total - i);
return combinations;
```

The current container might contain anything from zero to all the items. So iterate through those and total up all the combinations for the remaining containers that add up to the target minus the items in the current container.

Comment: Im sorry but I dont exactly understand so I tried it and it returns 0 every Time. Im not exactly sure, but dont I have to give the current Combinations number into combinationCount?

Comment: I just tried it out and it works perfectly for me. I tried it with 20 containers of size 10 to 29 and there are 20,030,010 combinations that add to 10.